# Alternative proof for the fact that a continuous function on a closed interval attains its boundaries.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$  be a continuous function. We are interested in showing that $\exists  \beta \in [a,b]$, such that $f(\beta) = M$, where M is its upper boundary.

I have managed to proof by myself the fact that any continuous function on a closed interval is bounded so I assume we can use this in our proof.

I was playing a little with the pencil, doing some test work, and the following idea came to my mind:

I defiend a new function $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = \frac{1}{M-f(x)}$. $g$ is obviously continuous on $[a,b]$, and we have $g(x)>0,\forall x \in [a,b]$.

Since $g$ is continouou on a closed interval, $g$ is bounded. Let $M_1$ be its upper boundary. Now we have that:

$$ \frac{1}{M-f(x)} \leq M_1  $$

This actually implies that:

$$f(x) \leq M - \frac{1}{M_1} < M $$

This can't be true! Because if it were true, $f$ wouldn't be bounded by $M$. So, here's what I don't get. I have arrived at a contradiction! But what have I managed to contradict? It seems to me that this contradiction arrived from the fact that $f$ was bounded. So have I proved that f can't be bounded? But this doesn't make any sense, because we know for sure that $f$ is bounded, since its continuous on a closed interval.

I feel that I am very close to prove the claim. Could you please help me realise what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You did prove the claim. What you managed to contradict is that $M-f(x)$ is never $0$, so that $g$ is indeed well-defined (and hence continuous).

Comment: $g$ is obviously continuous, *if* $g(x)<M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.

Comment: @Etienne Are you sure about that? It seems to me there is no contradiction and that he proved absolutely nothing. He just started with a false assumption, that is, that $g$ is "obviously" continuous. But the continuity/non-continuity of $g$ is exactly what we have to prove ?

Comment: @Amateur I'm pretty sure of that, Yes. maybe he was too quick with the "obviously continuous": he should have said "well-defined" before...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: perhaps, you mean *if $f(x)<M$*

Comment: Yes, I meant $f(x)<M$. This proof shows that, for any strict upper bound, we can find a lower upper bound.

Comment: In addendum with Nate Eldredge's answer, this is a good proof. In fact, I haven't seen it before for this claim. I'll have to remember it.

Answer (score 5):

You started your proof by saying "$g$ is obviously continuous", but this is not true in general.

However, it does follow if you *assume* that $f$ does not attain the value $M$.  So if you begin your proof by saying:

> Assume $f$ does not attain the value $M$.  Let $g(x) = \frac{1}{M-f(x)}$.  Now $g$ is continuous...

You now have a valid argument.  Since it leads to a contradiction, you may conclude that the initial *assumption* that $f$ does not attain the value $M$ must have been false.  So you have proved that $f$ does attain the value $M$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers that helped me to clarify my problem. One thing, though: if f attains its boundaries, such that there is a $\beta $ with $f(\beta) = M $, the when x tends to $\beta $ we have that g tends to infinity, and it should tend to $g(\beta) $ . Am I correct? I strongly believe that this is the explanation